# Uploading images in wagtail accepted but image is not shown

Tags: image, wagtail

Django 1.11.2
Wagtail 1.10.1
Apache2.4

I uploaded an image from my computer via the wagtail dashboard. Wagtail shows the image and I clicked "update".

Then I went back to images. There is no new image but a new card with the name of the new file. There is also a picture symbol with the file name of the picture. If I click this field I get the template to edit the image. But the image is not shown (Bildschirmfoto_2018_03_18_17_23_06.png).
[image: dashboard with image name but without image]
Why is the image not shown?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Apache to serve files from `/media/images/` (or whatever you've set as `MEDIA_ROOT` in your settings file). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: My settings:
MEDIA_ROOT =PROJECT_ROOT +'/spd/spd/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


My Apache2 configuration: 
Alias /media   /srv/spd20170804/spd/spd/media

Comment: The link in the dashboard says "https://schwachhausen-nord.de/media/images/image2_9iRVYvi.original.jpg". But in the directory there isn't it.